# Lookup a Message Driven Bean via JNDI

Tags: glassfish, jms, jndi

If I create a MessageDriven bean - is it available to other components in my app via JNDI? If so, how can I find/specify the name to look it up by?  I'm deploying to glassfish if that makes any difference?

Answer (score 0):

Assigning a JNDI name for an MDB is not required by Java EE specification (chapter 21.2.3 of EJB 3.0):

> At the minimum, the EJB container must provide a JNDI API name space to the enterprise bean
>   instances. The EJB container must make the name space available to an instance when the instance invokes the javax.naming.InitialContext default (no-arg) constructor.
>
> - The business interfaces of other enterprise beans
> - [...]

MDBs don't qualify, as they don't have a business interface. Besides, since wiring up an MDB in another EJB/MDB would have little sense (what's your use case, BTW?), is probably skipped in Glassfish.

I've seen that WebLogic, [for example](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/ejb/message_beans.html) allows that in its proprietary deployment descriptor, but I've never used it.